# Should oozie be installed on all the hadoop nodes inside a single hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I am running oozie over hadoop 1.0.3. I wanted to find out whether oozie has to be installed over all the hadoop nodes inside a single cluster ? Is it sufficient to install it on the master node (hadoop) only ? I searched through the oozie documentation, but could not find the answer to my question.

Thankyou,
Mohsin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) need not be installed on all the nodes in a cluster. It can be installed on a dedicated machine or along with any other framework. Check this [guide](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/DG_QuickStart.html) for a quick installation of Oozie.

Note that Oozie has got a client and a server component. The server component has a Scheduler and also a WorkFlow engine. And the WorkFlow engine used hPDL (Hadoop Process Definition Language) for defining the WorkFlow.